# How do I write a test class for a Doctrine entity class?

Tags: symfony, model, doctrine-orm, tdd, entity

I am working with Symfony2 and Doctrine 2. I am trying to adopt a TDD approach. Can someone give me a basic example of a unit test class for a Doctrine entity class please?

Sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think that unit testing of ``Doctrine`` entity class makes much sense since entity class should not contain any logic.

Comment: Thats true. Thanks for the advice. I guess it would make more sense to test the repository classes if they have custom logic/functions.

Comment: They don't have logic, but they have structure. Unit tests may test the structure. 
Also @marcoshoya gave an example of funcitional test that can be used to make sure that table structures haven't changed within migrations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a simple sample of unit test for an entity:

```
class MessageTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var Message
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
     * This method is called before a test is executed.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->object = new Message();
    }

    public function testGetterAndSetter() {

        $this->assertNull($this->object->getId());

        $date = new \DateTime();

        $this->object->setDate($date);
        $this->assertEquals($date, $this->object->getDate());

        $this->object->setMessage("message");
        $this->assertEquals("message", $this->object->getMessage());

        $this->object->setSuccess(true);
        $this->assertTrue($this->object->getSuccess());
    }
}
```

Comment: This test class test auto-generated methods of an Entity! Do you really need tests?